# Pandas dataframe if condition using isin on string

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is the sample data set.

```
test=pd.DataFrame({'class': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
                   'Value': [2, 1, 5, 4]
                   })
```

I would like to change column "Value" based on below condition
"If class is in 'A' or 'B' and Value>=4 change Value to '0' else keep the same"
Here is the built in function

```
def test_class(c):
    if c[(c['class'].isin(['A','B'])) & (c['Value']>=4)]:
        return 0
    else:
        return  c["Value"]
```

Applying on dataframe

```
test['Value'] = test.apply(test_class, axis=1)
```

Throwing below error

[image]

Expected output and highlighted below should be the change in value

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to use 'test_class' function with a loop in your case? If not, you could do:

```
test.loc[(test['class'].isin(['A','B'])) & (test['Value']>=4), 'Value'] = 0
```

Output:

```
    class   Value
0       A       2
1       B       1
2       C       5
3       A       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function `c['class']` is a simple string, so you can do:

```
def test_class(c):
    if (c['class'] in ['A','B']) & (c['Value']>=4):
        return 0
    else:
        return  c["Value"]

test['Value'] = test.apply(test_class, axis=1)
```

However, it's better to vecorize the function like this:

```
def test_class(c):

    return np.where((c['class'].isin(['A','B'])) & (c['Value']>=4), 0,
                    c['Value'])
```

Then you can call:

```
test['Value'] = test_class(test)
```

Comment: Thank you but I am seeing this "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,2) () (4,)"

Comment: @HKE I was too fast, you need to remove the otter `c[...]`. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
np.where((test['class'].isin(['A', 'B']))&(test.Value.ge(4)), 0, test['Value'])
```

You can also use `mask` method:

```
test.Value.mask((test['class'].isin(['A', 'B']))&(test.Value.ge(4)), other=0)
```

Output:

```
    class   Value   new_value
0     A       2         2
1     B       1         1
2     C       5         5
3     A       4         0
```